# Name specific index in ES using filebeat and logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elk

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: container
  stream: stdout
  paths:
    - /var/log/containers/*.log
  processors:
    - add_docker_metadata: ~

output.logstash:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["helm-logstash-security-logstash.elasticsearch:5055"]
---------------------------
input {
  beats {
    port => 5055
    
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "%{[docker][container][name]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    user => '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}'
    password => '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}'
  }
```

Following are my configs which do not work, I would want filebeat to somehow read the container name and pass that to logstash so the indexes i create are something of the format "container-name-YYYY-MM-DD"

Comment: In the Logstash config, if you add an `stdout` output instead of elasticsearch, how do your events look like?